# How to programmatically install vagrant plugins?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I have a Vagrant build that has a dependency on vagrant plugins.

I could document that users need to install those plugins, but ideally I would like to automatically install the required plugins.

How can I automatically install the required plugins as part of my build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on a [blog post](http://matthewcooper.net/2015/01/15/automatically-installing-vagrant-plugin-dependencies/) by Matt Cooper.  This solution worked for me.

The blog post describes adding the following lines to the top of your Vagrantfile:

```
required_plugins = %w( vagrant-omnibus vagrant-aws )
required_plugins.each do |plugin|
    exec "vagrant plugin install #{plugin};vagrant #{ARGV.join(" ")}" unless Vagrant.has_plugin? plugin || ARGV[0] == 'plugin'
end
```